# iterating through files with carriage returns

Tags: python

Is there a way to iterate through a text file using the syntax,

```
with open(filename,'r') as f:
  for line in f:
    print f
```

if the file only contains carriage returns and no newline characters?

So far all I can do is

```
with open(filename,'r') as f:
  for line in f.read().split('\r'):
    print f
```

But the files are sometimes huge. I don't want to modify the file using dos2unix because another software program needs it in the original format.

Comment: Have you tried it? I thought Python handles all kinds of newlines on its own (when reading files in text mode).

Comment: @delnan: yes -- it actually reads in the whole file in the first iteration.

Comment: Lines in the input can end in '\n', '\r', or '\r\n', and these are translated into '\n' before being returned to the caller.  Refer to https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/newline-conversion-in-python-3/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use Python's [universal newline support for `open()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open)

> In addition to the standard fopen() values mode may be `'U'` or `'rU'`. Python is usually built with universal newline support; supplying `'U'` opens the file as a text file, but lines may be terminated by any of the following: the Unix end-of-line convention `'\n'`, the Macintosh convention `'\r'`, or the Windows convention `'\r\n'`. All of these external representations are seen as `'\n'` by the Python program. If Python is built without universal newline support a mode with `'U'` is the same as normal text mode. Note that file objects so opened also have an attribute called newlines which has a value of `None` (if no newlines have yet been seen), `'\n'`, `'\r'`, `'\r\n'`, or a tuple containing all the newline types seen.

Comment: Ah, *this* was what I was thinking of. +1

Comment: great -- I just needed `open(filename,'rU')`

Comment: What to do if the file comes in as a request body?

Comment: DeprecationWarning: 'U' mode is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

You can use `open(filename, 'rU')`.

Comment: No need to add again an answer with the same solution IMHO