# Python skip first line .readlines( )[1:] not working?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, readline

If I remove [1:], if works fine and prints all data.

```
f = open("test.csv", "r")
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
print lines
```

result:

```
['title1,title2\raa,aaaa\rbb,bbbb\rcc,cccc']
```

but if I try to skip the first line by adding [1:]

```
f = open("test.csv", "r")
lines = f.readlines()[1:]
f.close()
print lines
```

it prints an empty array

```
[]
```

I'm using python 2.7.6.
Does anyone know why?

Comment: It seems your Python is not configured to support [universal newlines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0278/).

Comment: related (if not duplicate): [iterating through files with carriage returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174243/iterating-through-files-with-carriage-returns)

Comment: Try `f = open("test.csv", "rU")` instead of `f = open("test.csv", "r")`. Also, when dealing with a csv file, consider using the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

Comment: @sloth `U` only works with Python that already has universal newline support. And all it does is that it assigns the newlines found in that file to `.newlines` attribute of the file object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> result:
>
> ```
>  ['title1,title2\raa,aaaa\rbb,bbbb\rcc,cccc']
> ```
>
> but if I try to skip the first line by adding [1:] it prints empty array

It looks like you have a platform line encoding issue.  You're assuming that python reads this as a multi-line file; however, python only sees one line.

Modify your code to do this...

```
f = open("test.csv", "r")
lines = f.read().splitlines()   # Thanks to Ashwini's comment for tip
f.close()
print lines
```

Comment: You're trying to split a list, I'd go for `f.read().splitlines()`.