# How to load numpy arrays from a text file that contains stray carriage returns in addition to newlines?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a newline-line separated data file that contains stray carriage returns, for example:

```
printf '1 1 string1
2 2 str\ring2
3 3 string3
' > mydat.dat
```

When using Python lists, I can process this file correctly by using `newline='\n'` as mentioned at: [iterating through files with carriage returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174243/iterating-through-files-with-carriage-returns)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
xs = []
ys = []
labels = []
with open('mydat.dat', 'r', newline='\n') as f:
    for line in f:
        x, y, label = line.split(' ')
        xs.append(int(x))
        ys.append(int(y))
        labels.append(label)
print(xs)
print(ys)
print(repr(labels))
```

which prints the desired:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
['string1\n', 'str\ring2\n', 'string3\n']
```

My question is, does `numpy.loatxt` or a similar convenient function have have the capability to treat carriage returns analogously, without forcing me to manually process the file with `open`, or preprocess the file with `dos2unix`?

If I try:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import numpy
x, y = numpy.loadtxt('mydat.dat', dtype=int, unpack=True, usecols=(0, 1,))
print(x)
print(y)
```

then it fails with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 5, in <module>
    x, y = numpy.loadtxt('mydat.dat', unpack=True, usecols=(0, 1,))
  File "/home/ciro/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1141, in loadtxt
    for x in read_data(_loadtxt_chunksize):
  File "/home/ciro/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1061, in read_data
    vals = [vals[j] for j in usecols]
  File "/home/ciro/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1061, in <listcomp>
    vals = [vals[j] for j in usecols]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

because when it reaches `2 2 str\ring2`, it treats `ing2` as a line with a single entry.

Tested in Python 3.6.7, numpy 1.11.1, Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of giving the filename to `loadtxt`, you can open the file with the option `newline='\n'`, and give the file handler to numpy

```
with open('mydat.dat', 'r', newline='\n') as f:
    x, y = numpy.loadtxt(f, dtype=int, unpack=True, usecols=(0, 1,))
print(x)
print(y)
```

Comment: Ahhh, it takes file objects. Perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `genfromtxt`, which happens to work at least with your small example:

```
In [8]: import numpy
   ...: x, y = numpy.genfromtxt('mydat.dat', dtype=int, unpack=True, usecols=(0, 1,))
   ...: print(x)
   ...: print(y)
   ...: 
[1 2 3]
[1 2 3]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this produces wrong data in general e.g. if there were 4 columns instead: `printf '1 1 0\r0 1\n' > mydat.dat`.